# apache2 not working with port other than 80

Tags: apache, nginx

I have nginx running at port 80.

After installing apache2, I set its port to 82 (both in ports.conf and 000-default.conf).

I have tried opening the ip (i.e a.b.c.d:82) but its not opening. But if I set port to 80 and stop nginx then its opening.

I tried opening ip with the below format:

```
a.b.c.d:82
a.b.c.d - opening nginx site
```

I also tried setting dns to abc.mydomain.com  and opened

```
abc.mydomain.com (opening nginx site)
abc.mydomain.com:82 (not opening anything)
```

How to access it using apache with some port other than 80 ?

Please let me know for more questions.

Thanks.

Comment: First check if the http server starts at all. For that take a look into the http servers error log file.

Comment: Please provide path to http servers file

Comment: I suggest you look into a) your own configuration where that is actually defined and b) into the documentation. No sense for me to copy and paste all that here. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this way https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#port

but not working

Comment: The apache http server certainly _is_ able to bind to arbitrary ports. So the question is what is wrong in your setup. To find out you need to investigate. The first step is that error log file, no way around that.

Comment: Here is the output:

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Wed Dec 28 14:56:43.875920 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3256:tid 139797194794880] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Dec 28 14:56:44.936650 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3819:tid 140144479770496] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 28 14:56:44.936735 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3819:tid 140144479770496] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Please always add additional information to the question itself, not into comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131719/discussion-between-arkascha-and-user2349115).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion and investigation in the chat revealed that this actually was about a remote system, not a local development setup. That means that typically a package filter ("firewall") is in between client and sever. When using a non standard port for a "well known protocol" you need to open that port in the servers firewall for incoming traffic.

In this case using Ubuntu's `ufw` tool had been used to setup a simple package filter. Configuring the custom port 82 and allowing incoming traffic to it solved the issue at hand.